# Alternative to dragdealer.js that suports interpolation?

Tags: drag-and-drop, slider, scrollbar

I'm need to control the scrolling of an element, via an external handle, to do this, one can use the excellent dragdealer.js (http://code.ovidiu.ch/dragdealer/) but it seems it has not been updated since 2010, and there are some features that could need improving, for instance the ability to have "steps" in different sizes, and controlling the scroll-speed on the fly, if you for instance want to scroll the scrolling element between "slides" of different sizes.

Are there any more recent librarys/plugins that you think I should look at?